# Agrupar información de dos objetos con arreglos en un objeto

Tags: javascript

Estoy recibiendo información de dos endpoints diferentes

1° Tickets:

```json
[
    {
        "code": "",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
        "id": "j9KSq7SB79sKOGqUkL2e",
        "name": "asd",
        "provider": { "name": "COTO", "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp", "createdAt": "2022-01-07" },
        "spend": "400"
    },
    {
        "code": "",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
        "id": "kmh8Qi89KLnDZqlDDEh6",
        "name": "Nuevo",
        "provider": { "name": "COTO", "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp", "createdAt": "2022-01-07" },
        "spend": "562"
    }
]
```

2° Providers:

```json
[
    {
        "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
        "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp",
        "name": "COTO"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
        "id": "Bi9rh6tGCj8XP8GNTQLJ",
        "name": "CITAL"
    }
]
```

**Lo quiero obtener es el siguiente formato a partir de la información que obtengo de `providers`, agrupo los `providers` de todos los `tickets` y sumo los `spend`. Pero manteniendo el resto de los campos, y los `providers` que no se utilizaron en tickets también traerlos. Esta información se va mostrar en una tabla `providers` en una pagina web, necesito que mantenga el formato que trae del endpoint de proviers, pero con mas información (agrupando los spends)**

```json
[
    { "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp", "name": "COTO", "spend": 962, "createdAt": "2022-01-07" },
    { "id": "Bi9rh6tGCj8XP8GNTQLJ", "name": "CITAL", "spend": 0, "createdAt": "2022-01-07" }
]
```

Con el siguiente código lo que hago es poder obtener todos los `providers` según los `tickets` que obtengo.

```javascript
tickets.reduce(function (res, value) {
    const name = value.provider.name;
    const id = value.provider.id;
    if (!res[id]) {
      res[id] = {id: id,name: name, spend: 0 };
      result.push(res[id]);
    }
    res[id].spend += parseFloat(value.spend);
    return res;
  }, {});
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:
Como esta información es en base a los tickets, no de los `providers`, no tengo el campo `createdAt` de `provider` y ademas no me muestra los `providers` que no se utilizaron en `tickets`

```json
[
    { "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp", "name": "COTO", "spend": 962 }
]
```

No se como encarar este problema, ya "queme" los pocos recursos que tengo
Como puedo hacer para obtener el formato que necesito ?(mencionado anteriormente)

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me funciona bien así:

```js
tickets = [{
    "code": "",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
    "id": "j9KSq7SB79sKOGqUkL2e",
    "name": "asd",
    "provider": {
      "name": "COTO",
      "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-07"
    },
    "spend": "400"
  },
  {
    "code": "",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
    "id": "kmh8Qi89KLnDZqlDDEh6",
    "name": "Nuevo",
    "provider": {
      "name": "COTO",
      "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-07"
    },
    "spend": "562"
  }
];

providers = [{
    "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
    "id": "2bV8zlBCc07YeEv4pmHp",
    "name": "COTO"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-01-07",
    "id": "Bi9rh6tGCj8XP8GNTQLJ",
    "name": "CITAL"
  }
];

let result = [];
providers.forEach(element => combinacion(element));

function combinacion(elem) {
  const id = elem.id;
  const created = elem.createdAt;
  let combinado = [];
  if (!combinado[id]) {
    combinado[id] = {
      id: id,
      name: elem.name,
      spend: 0,
      createdAt: created
    };
    result.push(combinado[id]);
  }
  tickets.forEach(ticket => {
    const name = ticket.provider.name;
    if (name == elem.name) {
      combinado[id].spend += parseFloat(ticket.spend);
    }
  })
}

console.log(result);
```

Lo que hago es meter tu código en una función (por comodidad), y luego lo voy llamando en un `foreach` donde recorro el array de los proveedores. Entonces recupero los datos comunes en cada iteración y voy creando el array de objetos de salida con valor incial de 0, incluido el proveedor que te faltaba. Luego recorro los tickets y hago la suma, y todo se va almacenando en `result` hasta el final, donde lo muestro con el console.log.

Comment: Me sirve, lo puse resolver con el código que acabas de utilizar, te hago una consulta, es necesario el reduce? porque lo modifique y en vez de usar el `tickets.reduce()` lo cambie por `ticket.foreach()`

Comment: Y con el foreach te ha funcionado?  Lo digo porque lo he probado despues de dar esta respuesta y me perdia la suma, y por no tocar mas el codigo lo he dejado con el reduce

Comment: Si, ahí edite la pregunta e inserte el fragmento del código, si podes, decime que te parece.

Comment: Vale, ya veo porque a mi no me habia funcionado el forEach en los tickets... le puse un `function ()` de más y eso hacia que no se sumara el tema, es decir, lo puse asi:  `tickets.forEach(ticket => function(){` cuando tenia que ser asi:  `tickets.forEach(ticket => {`

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar en mi respuesta. Lo he dejado con el forEach.  No se si es buena idea dejar la resolución en tu pregunta, no creo que les guste a los moderadores.  Si ahora crees que mi respuesta ya da solución completa a tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para evitar que se quede pendiente eternamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu código lo pude resolver.